# Deleting rows according to the absence of a word in factor in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, grepl

I have a dataframe with text and author. I need to clean data in only one factor level to keep all the rows where one word is present. Here is a small example:

```
author(factor)   text

John             Pear Plum

Mary             Pear Apple Banana Grapes

Mike             Grapes Apple Peach

John             Banana Pear Apple

John             Apple Melon
```

This is the result I would like to obtain, to delete every row where the word Apple is not mentioned by John:

```
author(factor)   text

Mary             Pear Apple Banana Grapes

Mike             Grapes Apple Peach

John             Banana Pear Apple

John             Apple Melon
```

This is what I have tried:

```
df$author%in% "John"[!grepl("Apple", df$text, ignore.case = T),,drop = FALSE]
```

In response I obtain an error message:

```
  Error in "John"[!grepl("Apple", df$text, ignore.case = T),  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

I have looked suggestions about subsetting the data but I cannot find anything that resembles my case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% filter(!(author == 'John' & !str_detect(text, 'Apple')))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  author text                    
  <chr>  <chr>                   
1 Mary   Pear Apple Banana Grapes
2 Mike   Grapes Apple Peach      
3 John   Banana Pear Apple       
4 John   Apple Melon
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  author text                    
  <chr>  <chr>                   
1 John   Pear Plum               
2 Mary   Pear Apple Banana Grapes
3 Mike   Grapes Apple Peach      
4 John   Banana Pear Apple       
5 John   Apple Melon
```

Comment: @Jess, strange, is you data in the same format as you've shared above?

Comment: Sorry I have made a small mistake while rewriting the code! Now it works, thank you so much!